# What does the expression $\langle y^{(n)}|\otimes \,|\Psi_b\rangle$ mean?

Tags: quantum-gate, terminology-and-notation, projection-operator

I'm trying to understand the following paper, https://journals.aps.org/prresearch/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevResearch.3.013167, but I'm new to quantum computing. In it they use this expression:
$$\langle y^{(n)}|\otimes \,|\Psi_b\rangle.$$
What is this operator and what effect does it have on the state $\Psi_b$? I think it is some sort of projection of the state $y^{(n)}$ into $\Psi_b$ based on the context although that would be written as $|y^{(n)}\rangle\langle y^{(n)}|\Psi_b\rangle$. Thanks for the help.

Comment: are you referring to the equation at the end of page 3, first column? For doublestruck 1 see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/33303/173147. Easiest way is to paste the unicode symbol: 

Comment: Yes that is the equation I was referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It likely simply refers to a partial projection. It will probably be clearer using some parentheses:
$$\langle y^{(n)}|\otimes \,|\Psi_b\rangle
\equiv
(\langle y^{(n)}|\otimes )|\Psi_b\rangle$$
where  is the identity matrix.

For example, you have
$$(\langle 0|\otimes )(|00\rangle+|01\rangle+|10\rangle)
= |0\rangle+|1\rangle.$$